# URL given have fileNotFoundException

Tags: java, url, stream, filenotfoundexception

I have the following code, it works totally fine on my local development server, but when I uploaded to the deployment server, I always hit file not found Exception

```
String urlStr = "http://" + getContext().getRequest().getServerName() +
getContext().getServletContext().getContextPath() + "test.action";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
InputStream input = url.openStream(); //Error always occurs here, it gives me the correct URL but it says file not found.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Name of your Application server?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: The application server is EatJ server

Comment: Why dont you print out the `urlStr` to see what's in there?

Comment: I tried, it is a proper URL and I use that URL to paste it on my browser, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Because its a HTTP URL the correct way would be as follows.

```
String urlStr = "http://" + getContext().getRequest().getServerName() +
        getContext().getServletContext().getContextPath() + "test.action";
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED) { 
    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
}
```

Comment: Yea ... I didn't think it would.  What value is `conn.getResponseCode()` giving you?

Comment: And 404 means "not found".

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the help, I am not sure why it doesn't work, but I've rendered the HTML in my backend logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @deadlock's comments is probably the key to solving this.

You are getting a `FileNotFoundException` because the remote server is sending a 404 Not Found response.  The most likely explanation is that you are attempting to connect using the wrong URL.  Print out the URL string before you try to connect.

---

All the evidence is pointing to the fact that the server is sending "404 Not Found" responses ... for both versions of the code.  This normally means that your URL is wrong.  But it is also possible for it to be other things:

- You may be using different proxies in the Java and browser cases, resulting in the Java case reaching some server that doesn't understand the URL.
- It is conceivable that the server is implementing some anti web scraping mechanism, and sending you 404 responses `cos this thinks (rightly) that your requests aren't coming from a web browser,

Comment: I tried, it is a correct URL, I Pasted the same url into my browser, it returns me a result.